# Type '()' cannot conform to 'View' in SwiftUI NavigationStack

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm new to Swift and I'm stuck with Navigation problems in xcode 15.
When I call the function:

```
randomizeDestination()
```

an error "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View' " appears.

When I replace it with a different function:

```
func getScreen2() -> some View {}
```

with pretty much the same content, except it has return value instead of "currentDestination", the error disappears and another screen appears. However, the switch case only gets executed once.

If I use this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: currentDestination, isActive: $readyToNavigate,
                               label: {
```

The program works as intended, but a deprecated warning appears.

My code is below:

```
struct ContentView: View { 
@State private var currentDestination: AnyView? 
@State private var readyToNavigate : Bool = false
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack{
            //Background Image 

            NavigationStack {
                VStack {
                    Button {

                        readyToNavigate = true
                    } label: {
                        //Text("Navigate Button")
                        ZStack {
                            // some Button Icon code
                        } // end ZStack
                        
                          // some Text attribute code     
                        
                    } // Label

                } // VStack

                .navigationTitle("Navigation")
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $readyToNavigate) {
                    randomizeDestination()

                } // NavDes
            } // NavStack
        } // ZStack
    } // NavView
} // Body

func randomizeDestination()  {

    let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0...30)
    print("RI: ", randomIndex)
    switch randomIndex {
    case 0...5:
        currentDestination = AnyView(NextScreen1())
    case 6...11:
        currentDestination = AnyView(NextScreen2())
    case 12...18:
        currentDestination = AnyView(NextScreen3())
    case 19...24:
        currentDestination = AnyView(NextScreen4())
    default:
        currentDestination = AnyView(NextScreen5())
    }
} // end func
} // end Struct
```

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks.

Comment: As the error says, you need to provide a `View` for the destination. You are not doing that -- you're just calling a function. Also, you should watch "Demystify SwiftUI" from WWDC for info on why using `AnyView` is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

To be within `body`, you have to return a view. The other functions that you tried **do** return views, and thus don't cause an issue. However, you can think of `randomizeDestination` as producing merely void, which is undisplayable. Think in terms of what can be returned to be displayed, and it might make more sense.